# How to set ListView ItemsStackPanel orientation by code?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

This is simple by `XAML` but how to do this same by `C#`? Need to change `Orientation` between `Horizontal` and `Vertical`.

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Problem solved. The next code works well.

```
        if(MyListView != null)
        {
            ListView ListViewInfo = MyListView;
            ItemsStackPanel ItemsStackPanelInfo = ListViewInfo.ItemsPanelRoot as ItemsStackPanel;
            if ("something is true or false") ItemsStackPanelInfo.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            else ItemsStackPanelInfo.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        }
```